# Magento addCustomOption does not update quantity

Tags: php, magento

I am facing an issue, when I add custom options to the product and then add it to cart, it does not update cart quantity if the cart contains same product with same custom options like below

```
$additionalOptions = array(
[0] => array
    (
        [label] => "Custom option 0"
        [value] => "Custom value 0"
    ),
[1] => array
    (
        [label] => "Custom option 1"
        [value] => "Custom value 1"
    ),
[2] => array
    (
        [label] => "Custom option 2"
        [value] => "Custom value 2"
    ),
[3] => array
    (
        [label] => "Custom option 3"
        [value] => "Custom value 3"
    )
);
$product->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
```

But when there is only single item in array, it works.

Can someone help me where I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How you'r inserting the product into cart??

I think you should use like this:

First you'll need to check if the product you'r using it's already in the cart or not, and if it using the same option, i sugest you to use something like that: (need test and small fixes i think)

```
   $items = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

Check item by item to see if you need to add or update, so you can use:

```
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->
              updateItems(array('product_id'=>array('qty'=>'12321321')));
```

This should do the trick.